# Data Loading very slow from on-prem Data Lake to azure Data Lake Storage though Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, on-premises-instances, azure-migrate

I want to load data from on-prem (Data Lake) storage to azure Data Lake storage gen2.

For this,
I have created on-prem windows server and installed self hosted Integration Run-time on it.And connected to on-prem Data Lake(HIVE) from Azure Data Factory.

In Azure Data Factory I have created a pipeline with copy activity and provided source as my on-prem Data Lake(Hive).And given SQL query to pull data.Likewise I need to add multiple copy activities for multiple tables.

I have tried with single copy activity only in my pipeline.

Here comes my problem:My pipeline is taking so much of time to load data into Data Lake.

My windows server in which my Integration Run-time is located has Bandwidth of 10Gbps.But it still loads very slow.

I have just tried to pull 20,000 records.And it took around 20 minutes to load data. The Throughput i was getting is around 15kbps which is very low.

How can I improve the performance of my activity so that it will be faster.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the configuration of Integration Runtime? How much RAM or nodes you have configured?

Also, are you using Express Route or Side by Side VPN, Express Route is a faster option

The recommended minimum configuration for the self-hosted integration runtime machine is a 2-GHz processor with 4 cores, 8 GB of RAM, and 80 GB of available hard drive space.

Comment: We need an Integration Run-time to connect to on-prem right.

So I have procured a windows server near to my data centre and created Integration Run-time on it. And connected to on-prem server through ADF. My windows server has Bandwidth of 10Gbps.32 core, 16gb RAM, 2.79 Ghz

Comment: ok, please try seeing this article for troubleshooting:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-performance-troubleshooting